The existence of $f \in \Lambda^2(V^{*}) \setminus \{0\}$ such that $f(\xi_1, \xi_2) = 0$
Suppose $\xi_1$, $\xi_2$ are linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{K}^n$, where $n \geq 2$. Please determine if there exists $f \in \Lambda^2(V^{*}) \setminus \{0\}$ such that $f(\xi_1, \xi_2) = 0$.

@rafilou2003 So how can I explain the (3) above $V$?

I deleted my comment as I am still unsure, but to me the (3) meant that when you consider a function $V\times V\to V$, "$V$" appears three times. I deleted as I am unsure as to whether $\Lambda(V^{(3)})$ references any bilinear map from $V\times V$ to $V$, or a specific type.

@rafilou2003 And also I need to consider the solvability of the problem (How terrible)

I see you just edited the question to $\Lambda^2(V^{*})$, which sounds like the set of bilinear forms of $V$, so the set of bilinear functions $V\times V\to \mathbb K$.

If the symbol denotes, as I surmise, the exterior square, then the answer to the question whether there is a such an $f$ should be yes if $n > 2$ and no is $n = 2$.

$\wedge^2(V^)\cong \wedge^2(V)^$, and $\wedge^2(V)$ has dimension $\binom{n}{2}$, so we are asking if there is a non-zero functional from a $\binom{n}{2}$ dimensional vector space which has a particular element in its kernel.  As long as $\binom{n}{2}>1$, the answer is yes.

@Aaron This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

@AnneBauval Understood.  I have reposted the comment as an answer.

We have that $\Lambda^k(V^*)\cong (\Lambda^k V)^*$, and under this isomorphism, we are looking to find a non-zero functional that vanishes on $\xi_1 \wedge \xi_2$.  However, if $\dim(V)=n$, then $\dim \Lambda^k V=\binom{n}{k}$, and given any proper subspace of a finite dimensional vector space, there is always a non-zero functional vanishing on that subspace (it is easy to see if you take a basis for the subspace, complete it to a basis for the whole space, and then using coordinates with respect to that basis you project onto the last coordinate).  Therefore, as long as $\binom{n}{2}>1$, we can find a non-zero functional vanishing on any particular vector $\Lambda^2 V$.

I'm assuming $\Lambda^2(V^{*})$ is the set of bilinear forms of $V$, so the set of bilinear maps $V\times V\to \mathbb K$.
First, complete $(\xi_1,\xi_2)$ into a basis $(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)$ of $V = \mathbb K^n$. Now, for any $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, we denote by $\xi_i^*:V\to \mathbb K$ the linear form which to any $v\in V$, writing $v= \sum_{k=1}^n v_k\xi_k$ with $v_1,\dots,v_n \in \mathbb K$, outputs $\xi_i^*(v) = v_i$.
Then the bilinear form $f:V\times V\to \mathbb K$ defined by $\forall v,w\in V, f(v,w) = \xi_1^*(v)\xi_1^*(w)$ matches our expectations:

$f$ is bilinear: easy to verify using that $\xi_1^*$ is linear;
$f$ is not zero everywhere: $f(\xi_1,\xi_1) = 1\cdot 1 = 1 \neq 0$ because $\xi_1 = \mathbf 1\cdot \xi_1 + 0\cdot\xi_2 + \dots +0\cdot\xi_n$.
$f(\xi_1,\xi_2) = 1\cdot 0 = 0$ because $\xi_2 = \mathbf 0\cdot \xi_1 + 1\cdot\xi_2 + 0\cdot\xi_3 + \dots +0\cdot\xi_n$.


I mistakenly upvoted your answer.  You are confusing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra

It is indeed confusing : ( Two $Λ$ doesn't have the same definition.
